# Changing locale using vi18n removes query and hash

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

Im building a one page website using vuejs and vi18n for the locale. Here's the scenario, when I click on one of my navigation link it scrolls to view the specific section of the page.

```
localhost/en/#about
```

changing the locale works , it changes from english to japanese and vice versa. But I noticed that the `#about` is removed.

```
localhost/jp/
```

is there a way that when changing the locale it wont remove the hash?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the hash will be removed by default when routing changes.

So you can do it in another way, store the `#hash` in storage before routing changes:

```js
window.localStorage.setItem('hash', window.location.hash)
```

and then, in the routing hook:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  //...
  let hashCache = window.localStorage.getItem('hash')
  let toUrl = to.path + hashCache ? `#${hashCache}` : ''
  //...
  next(toUrl)
  //...
})
```